# SonarQube analysis of JavaScript files causes "GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have been trying to analyze a project with a mixture of Java and JavaScript in SonarQube. The analyzer seems to have no problem with the Java files but when trying to analyze one of the application's javascript files, I got the following warning below. We have excluded all of the third party libraries using SonarQube's file exclusions and only included those that are being developed/maintained by the application team:

```
    [WARN] [14:00:10.103] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 38,121ms last 8 cycles average is 4,765ms
 [WARN] [14:00:10.103] [CHECKPOINT_WRITER] WARNING Transaction neither committed nor rolled back Transaction_100000002 depth=1 status=<ts=26,579 tc=UNCOMMITTED mvv=0>
 Exception in thread "CHECKPOINT_WRITER" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:834)
    at com.persistit.TransactionIndex.checkpointAccumulatorSnapshots(TransactionIndex.java:1102)
    at com.persistit.CheckpointManager.createCheckpoint(CheckpointManager.java:247)
    at com.persistit.CheckpointManager.pollCreateCheckpoint(CheckpointManager.java:197)
    at com.persistit.CheckpointManager.runTask(CheckpointManager.java:300)
    at com.persistit.IOTaskRunnable.run(IOTaskRunnable.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I looked at the source file that the development team gave me and it looks like a pretty standard .js file. The only thing I see is that it uses an object alias of $ for jQuery. The JS plugin version that we are using is 2.4.

Comment: Could provide the full log please and would you have the ability to test if you reproduce the issue with JavaScript plugin version 2.8?

Comment: Hi Linda, I can provide the log. I will send it in a separate email. Yes, we can test with version 2.8 of the JavaScript plugin, however, it may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered such issue lately. What I did to solve this is to edit the sonar wrapper configuration.

In Mac:

```
$ vim /usr/local/Cellar/sonar/5.2/libexec/conf/wrapper.conf
```

Look for wrapper.java.maxmemory and set it's value.

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory=3
```

Default value is 3. I've tried to increase this one and everything works fine after restarting the service.

```
sonar restart
```